# How to use grunt-sass to lint on the fly

Tags: gruntjs, node-sass

Was wondering if it is possible to lint my sass code on the fly with grunt-sass? Right now, I'm trying to remove ruby altogether from a project and it uses grunt-scss-lint for linting (which uses sass via ruby).

Thanks for any info/pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **sass-lint**
>   All Node Sass linter!
>   A Node-only Sass linter for both sass and scss syntax!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-lint

Note: I never used it. But seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I discounted it because I looked at it recently and it was in alpha, but it's making good progress now.

Comment: Let me know how this works for you. Might give it a spin myself.

Comment: On the whole, it seems to do the job. Im running into some trouble configuring the rules, but making progress. Thanks again for the reminder of this project's existence.